# Anti-virus Software downloads

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I don't have any ant-software installed on my PC.
I have Windows Vista and would like to install Microsoft Security Essentials.
Will having only this on my laptop be enough?
What do I need to make sure I have on my laptop to be secure while using the net?

Once I do that, will I need to download another software?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MS Security Essentials is definitely better than no security software. The benefits being that it is free and doesn't consume a lot of resources. Various vendors claim their products are better so it's tough to say which is the best.

Using an up to date browser, not opening unknown email attachments, avoiding questionable websites and not installing unknown software are also some of the ways to stay secure.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Panda Cloud Free Anti-Virus](http://www.cloudantivirus.com/) since its consumes even less resources. I'm using it from last 2 years, without any issues.

Scan your PC every month using [Malwarebytes Anti Malware Free](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free). It remove all traces of malware including worms, trojans, rootkits, rogues, dialers, spyware and more.